# Change date from database into an array

Tags: php, database, date

I am wondering how to the change date from this

```
Db -> holiday -> holidayDate (type date) = 2015-01-01, 2015-01-03, 2015-02-19, 2015-03-21, 2015-04-03, 2015-05-01, 2015-05-14, 2015-05-16, 2015-06-02, 2015-07-17, 2015-07-18, 2015-08-17, 2015-09-24, 2015-10-14, 2015-12-25
```

Here is the code

```
$sql = "select * from holiday order by holidayDate ";
//echo $sql;
$ambil_data = mysql_query($sql);
if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data))
{
     $tglLibur2 = $data['holidayDate'];
}
else
        {
            echo mysql_error();
        }

function selisihHari($tglAwal, $tglAkhir) 

{
    $tglLibur = array("'".$tglLibur2."'"); <= i just want to get this array from db
    $pecah1 = explode("-", $tglAwal);
    $date1 = $pecah1[2];
    $month1 = $pecah1[1];
    $year1 = $pecah1[0];


    $pecah2 = explode("-", $tglAkhir);
    $date2 = $pecah2[2];
    $month2 = $pecah2[1];
    $year2 =  $pecah2[0];

    $jd1 = GregorianToJD($month1, $date1, $year1);
    $jd2 = GregorianToJD($month2, $date2, $year2);

    $selisih = ($jd2 - $jd1);
    $libur1 = 0;
    $libur2 = 0;
    $libur3 = 0;
    for($i=1; $i<=$selisih; $i++)
    {
        $tanggal = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month1, $date1+$i, $year1);
        $tglstr = date("Y-m-d", $tanggal);

        if (in_array($tglstr, $tglLibur))
        {
            $libur1++;
        }
        if ((date("N", $tanggal) == 7))
        {
            $libur2++;
        }
        if ((date("N", $tanggal) == 6))
        {
            $libur3++;
        }

    }
    return $selisih-$libur1-$libur2-$libur3;


}
```

into this

```
 $tglLibur = array("2015-01-01","2015-01-03","2015-02-19",
 "2015-03-21","2015-04-03","2015-05-01","2015-05-14","2015-05-16",
 "2015-06-02","2015-07-17","2015-07-18","2015-08-17","2015-09-24",
 "2015-10-14","2015-12-25");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your function `selisihHari` doesn't have access to the variable `tglLibur2` you're using inside it. So I'm thinking you didn't post your full code here. But what you're looking for can be done with the following code:

```
$tglLibur = array()
foreach($tglLibur2 as $date){
    $tglLibur[] = $date;
}
```

But what you're doing in your fetch code doesn't make sense. You keep overwriting the same variable. To change that do the following:

```
$tglLibur2 = array();
if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data))
{
     $tglLibur2[] = $data['holidayDate'];
}
```

This should give you the array you're looking for. That way you can get rid of your function all together.

Comment: ehm.. i post full code now.. so sorry i'm not post full code before

Comment: @terenzadvent answer remains the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you aren't looping through each row and that `$data['holidayDate']` is a string of dates, comma delimited, just change:

`$tglLibur2 = $data['holidayDate'];`

to

`$tglLibur[] = explode(', ', $data['holidayDate']);`